# Spring data Redis to Elastic Cache Connection Checklist

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, architecture, spring-data-redis

How to connect to AWS ELasticCache Redis Cluster using Spring-data-redis. 
I am using redis as a datastore and would like to achieve

- High availability
- Low Latency

Assuming :

- Auth required
- Data encryption at transit required
- Cluster mode on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.config;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JedisClientConfiguration getJedisClientConfiguration(@Value("$REDIS_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT}") final Duration timeout) {

        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfigurationBuilder = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfigurationBuilder.connectTimeout(timeout);
        jedisClientConfigurationBuilder.usePooling();       
        return jedisClientConfigurationBuilder.build(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisClusterConfiguration getRedisClusterConfiguration(@Value("${REDIS_HOST}") final String host,
            @Value("${REDIS_PORT}") final Integer port) {

        RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
        redisClusterConfiguration = redisClusterConfiguration.clusterNode(host, port);
        return redisClusterConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory  jedisConnectionFactory(
            @Qualifier("getRedisClusterConfiguration") final RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration, 
            @Qualifier("getJedisClientConfiguration") final JedisClientConfiguration jedisClientConfiguration) {

        JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration, jedisClientConfiguration);
        return connectionFactory;

    }
}
```

Missing

- shrad
- auth
- Data encryption ..To be done at AWS ElastiCache